# Resetting the default word for launching programs in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

A while back, I was trying to follow some fixes online for running exe files on the network and some of them involved making changes in the registry.

Since then, the default word in the context menu to launch programs changed to `"%1" %*` (see below screenshot) which I do know was part of what a fix told me to change.

[image: Default word that launches programs changed]

I have only just got round to putting this right but I cannot recall how to change this back to the default.

I am looking at the keys like:-

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open\Default
```

Which do have the value as `"%1" %*` but I am unsure exactly which key in the registry controls the word (I think 'Open') used in the Windows 7 context menu like above.

Can anyone point me to the right key to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `(default)` value data here:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open\command
```

Must be set to `"%1" %*`

And, select the following key.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open
```

Right-click `(default)` and choose `Delete`. It should now read `value not set`.

That fixes the menu caption - setting it to `Open`.

**REG file to automate the above**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open\Default]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open]
@=-

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"
"IsolatedCommand"="\"%1\" %*"
```

Copy the above lines to Notepad, save as `exefix.reg`. Start `Regedit.exe` (right-click `Regedit.exe` and choose `Run as Administrator`) and import the REG file via the File menu.

Or run the .exe fix REG file available [here](http://www.winhelponline.com/fileasso/exe_fix_w7.zip) (zipped).

Comment: Those keys are both already set to `"%1" %*` - must be a different key controlling the word... :D

Comment: The registry path you mentioned in the original post is incorrect. You're probably checking the wrong location. Also make sure the `IsolatedCommand` value exists with correct data.

Comment: I've checked loads of paths, including those in your answer...

Comment: Then post a file association dump for .exe files (using [FileTypeDiag](https://www.pretentiousname.com/miscsoft/)) which helps find what's wrong with the association settings.

Comment: I applied the fix all the same and as expected, it didn't fix the problem. Looking for another key that has changed the default word to launch programs.

Comment: The issue is not the file association incorrect. If I click the command, it runs the programs correctly and without issue. I have changed the actual word which I want to change back. There is no issue with exe file association... Just to clarify.

Comment: Ok. I got it. I've updated the REG file, that should change the label back to "open"

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't appear to have fixed the issue still... :/ sorry.

Comment: Here is a link to the [report on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5BWPYTDK).

Comment: Solved in chat... Deleted value at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open\(Default)` (so that the value reverts to (value not set). Now fixed! Thanks :)